# Common Lispでのインスタンス初期化の書き方が分からない

Tags: common-lisp

CLOSでBMIを計算するクラスを作りたいのですが、コンストラクターの使い方が解りません。

最終的に以下の様な形で初期化を呼び出ししたいのですが、どうソースを書いていいのか解りません。

```lisp
(defparameter person-a (make-instance 'bmi :height 170 :weight 60))
```

とりあえず書いてみたコードは以下になりますが、`(bmi-bmi x)`が変数でないというコンパイルエラーが起きます。
丸投げのようで心苦しいのですが、どう書けば最初に書いた書き方で、スロット`bmi`に計算したbmiを束縛できるのでしょうか？

```lisp
;;;
;;; bmi.lisp
;;;

;;; クラス定義
(defclass bmi ()
  ((height :accessor bmi-height :initform 0 :initarg height)
   (weight :accessor bmi-weight :initform 0 :initarg weight)
   (bmi :accessor bmi-bmi :initform 0)))

;;; 初期化
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((x bmi))
  (setq meter-height (/ (bmi-height x) 100))
  (setq tmp-value (/ (bmi-weight x) (* meter-height meter-height)))
  (setq (bmi-bmi x) (/ (floor (* tmp-value 10)) 10)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元の Lisp 処理系は `GNU CLISP 2.49.93+ (2018-02-18)` なのですが、`initialize-instance` を override する場合には、引数に `&rest _` を指定する必要があるので、以下ではその様にしています。また、`(setq (bmi-bmi x) ...)` では `setq` ではなく `setf` を使います。

```lisp
(defclass bmi ()
  ((height :accessor bmi-height :initform 0 :initarg :height)
   (weight :accessor bmi-weight :initform 0 :initarg :weight)
   (bmi :accessor bmi-bmi :initform 0)))

;;; 初期化
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((x bmi) &rest _)
  (let* ((meter-height (/ (bmi-height x) 100))
         (tmp-value (/ (bmi-weight x) (* meter-height meter-height))))
    (setf (bmi-bmi x) (float (/ (floor (* tmp-value 10)) 10)))))

(defparameter person-a (make-instance 'bmi :height 170 :weight 60))

(describe person-a)

;; #<BMI #x000010000032E391> is an instance of the CLOS class #1=#<STANDARD-CLASS BMI>.
;; Slots:
;;   HEIGHT   = 170
;;   WEIGHT   = 60
;;   BMI      = 20.7
;; 
;;  170 is an integer, uses 8 bits, is represented as a fixnum.
;; 
;;  60 is an integer, uses 6 bits, is represented as a fixnum.
;; 
;;  20.7 is a float with 24 bits of mantissa (single-float).
```

Answer (score 1):

ストレートな回答は既にあるので、プログラミングスタイル的な観点から回答します。
Common Lispではメソッドはクラスに従属していないため、クラスというモジュールの中で計算をするという意識が希薄です。
大抵は、関数+データ構造でのプログラミングをベースにクラスの継承機構を活用するというスタイルになります。
そのため、今回のようなBMIの計算についても、データの置き場所であるオブジェクトとデータのアクセサ(メソッド)は分離して記述します。

```lisp
(defclass person ()
  ((cm-height :initarg :cm-height :initform 0 :accessor cm-height)
   (kg-weight :initarg :kg-weight :initform 0 :accessor kg-weight)))

(defmethod m-height ((person person))
  (/ (cm-height person) 100))

(defmethod compute-bmi ((person person))
  ;; BMI ＝ 体重kg ÷ (身長m)^2
  (/ (kg-weight person) (expt (m-height person) 2)))
```

```lisp
(setq person-a (make-instance 'person :cm-height 170.0 :kg-weight 60.0))

(compute-bmi person-a)
→ 20.761246
```

なお、入門的なトピックに関しては、広井誠氏の「お気楽 CLOS プログラミング入門」が参考になると思います。
例題となるトピックが他のプログラミング言語と共通のため、一般的なCommon Lispのスタイルではありませんが、他の言語を既に習得している人からすると逆に分かり易いかもしれません。
http://www.nct9.ne.jp/m_hiroi/clisp/index.html#clos